openedge windows gui slight graphical differences between users
v11.7.10 windows server
i'm working on a windows gui system. when i run a screen in dev i get slightly different handling of gui components to others.
e.g. i have a rectangle with a text label placed on it. on mine the text is displayed correctly. on a colleague's machine the text is truncated slightly.
it is as if the width/font ratios have changed somehow. anyone know the best place to look for what might cause this?
ini? registry? screen resolutions etc.
NB. we are both running on VMs that should be identical.

Providing pictures showing the differences might help

Check windows font size settings. Maybe one VM is zoomed? Or screens have different sizes or something else differs.
